# [xcode]unexpected '@' in program

Tags: xcode

I have a code like this

```
Initialize List View Controller
MTListViewController *listViewController = [[MTListViewController alloc] init];
// Initialize Navigation Controller
UINavigationController *listNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:listViewController];
// Initialize Tab Bar Controller
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
// Configure Tab Bar Controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[listNavigationController]];
```

and i am getting error "unexpected '@' in program" at last line. so whats wrong?? My xcode ersion is 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My xcode ersion is 4.2

Support for the new array literals is not available until Xcode 4.4. You need to use the equivalent old syntax:

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:listNavigationController]];
```